# Transaction not proceed on private net

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I am trying to send ether on private network. from chain1 to chain2.
But it does not proceed. (But no error occures.)

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
4999580000000000000

> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[2])

0
```

I unlocked my account too...

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1])
Unlock account 0xddc25843a212978640dedb119b9720f38da50d09
Passphrase: 
true
```

Transaction from the chain1 to the chain2

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[1], to: eth.accounts[2], value: web3.toWei(2, "ether")})
"0x876cdad3f665434816a531f2bd303414d8c72b16339d6ff84f22ecafd354e666"
```

It looks like the transaction has been processed but..

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[2])
0
```

It did not..

Comment: Are you mining the chain?

Comment: @Joe now?? I am not!

Comment: it says

> eth.getTransaction('0x876cdad3f665434816a531f2bd303414d8c72b16339d6ff84f22ecafd354e666')
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,

Comment: You need to be mining for a transaction to go through

Comment: I see. You mean, 
 miner.start()  ??

Comment: It still did not work...mhh

Comment: It wont be instant you need to start the miner and wait for a block with a transaction in it

Comment: Assuming it looks something like this http://imgur.com/a/bI84G you should see a line that says "commit new work on block X with 1 txs". and then "mined block #X" (where X is the block with the transaction in). When you see this the transaction has finished

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @joe on the comment, the problem was that I was not mining.
On the private net, you need to be mining to get the transaction done.